# Django Migrations: How to mark a migration as a parent of other apps migrations?

Tags: django, django-migrations

I'm trying to create a new Django application whose migrations depend on other apps migrations. I want migrations on the other apps to have a dependency on migrations on the new application, even when the new application doesn't reference at all the models at the other apps.

For example, let's say I have application `A` (an existing app) and application `B` (my new application):

A has a migration called `A.0001`, and B has a migration called `B.0001` which depends on `A.0001`. I now make a change at `A.MyModel`, so I need to run `python manage.py makemigrations` to generate a new migration `A.0002`.

What I want is `A.0002` to automatically depend on `B.0001`.

**How can I specify this dependency on new migrations in `A` without having to do it by hand each time I modify a model in A?**
I tried to add empty modifications of models in `A` at the migration `B.0001`, but I haven't got it to work and it looks very hacky to me.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that doesn't exactly solve what I asked, but can be a workaround for some people, so I will post it here.

There is an undocumented field of the django.Migration class, called `run_before`, that works just like an inverse `dependencies`.

`A.0002` will depend on `B.0001` if I simply define `run_before = [ A.0002 ]` at `B.0001`.